# Create multiple pivot tables assigned to dataframes after iterating

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pivot-table

Sample data set:

```
  ID  1  2  3  X  Y  Z
0   1  2  1  2  3  3  4
1   2  1  3  1  4  3  4
2   3  2  2  1  2  4  3
3   4  3  2  1  2  3  3
4   5  1  2  2  1  3  2
5   6  2  3  2  4  4  2
​
```

```
cross1 = pd.crosstab(sample["1"], org1_df["X"])
cross2 = pd.crosstab(sample["2"], org1_df["X"])
cross3 = pd.crosstab(sample["3"], org1_df["X"])
cross4 = pd.crosstab(sample["1"], org1_df["Y"])
cross5 = pd.crosstab(sample["2"], org1_df["Y"])
cross6 = pd.crosstab(sample["3"], org1_df["Y"])
cross7 = pd.crosstab(sample["1"], org1_df["Z"])
etc.
```

I want to loop through this code replacing "Column 1" and "Column X" with new columns ("Column 2" and "Column Y") in order to produce a new crosstab and assign that crosstab to a new dataframe. It works once, manually, very easily. This provides a count of the answers to a Survey Question by category, in this case, Business Type.

```
1 = Large Business
2 = Small Business
3 = Non-profit
```

```
    cross1 = pd.crosstab(sample["1"], sample["X"])
print(cross1)
```

```
X  1  2  3  4
1            
1  1  0  0  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  0  1  0  0
```

​

I need the iteration so I have multiple dataframes:

cross1
cross2
cross3
cross4
... etc.

```
demo_questions = 
['1', '2', '3']

survey_questions = 
['X', 'Y', 'Z']

for d, s in [demo_questions, survey_questions]:
    cross[d] = pd.crosstab(sample[d], sample[s])
```

I tried the above but received the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 1
----> 1 for d, s in [demo_questions, survey_questions]:
      2     cross[d] = pd.crosstab(sample[d], sample[s])

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: I placed a simplified data set in the question. Thanks for the suggestion. @BERA

Comment: Thanks! That answer worked for the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary to store the pivot tables, then iterate over the combinations of demo questions and survey questions and generate frequecy tables inside a dict comprehension

```
cross = {
    f'{d}_{s}': 
        pd.crosstab(df[d], df[s])
    for d in demo_questions
    for s in survey_questions
}
```

Now you can access the results by indexing the dictionary

```
print(cross['1_X'])

X  1  2  3  4
1            
1  1  0  0  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  0  1  0  0
```